# centering text in a span tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to center text within the context of the div it sits in. I want:

[image]

I have:

```
#previewOnlyWarning span{color: white; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 150%; left: 37%; top: 0.8%;}
#previewOnlyWarning {position:absolute; top: 0%; left: 35%; width: 25%; height: 4.5%; background: #ff0000; display:block; z-index: 1100}
```

In template this sites at the highest level, siblings to high elements, highest z-index of course:

```
<div id="previewOnlyWarning"><span>FOR PREVIEW ONLY<br><br>
                                Do not distribute links from this site.</span>
</div>
```

I get this:

[image]

These pics are missing about 1/3 of the page to the right of them but show the point. 
When I had text in `p` tags not in one single `span` it sat low (red space above it) and was ugly. How can I center this text that already has `text-align:center`? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<span>` is an inline element, the width is decided by the content it contains, so `text-align` doesn't have any effects.

You could set `text-align:center;` on the container, which is a block element `<div>`.

```css
#previewOnlyWarning {
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
}
#previewOnlyWarning span {
}
```

```html
<div id="previewOnlyWarning">
  <span>FOR PREVIEW ONLY<br><br> Do not distribute links from this site.</span>
</div>
```

Or set `span{display:block;}` to make it occupies the container width.

```css
#previewOnlyWarning {
  background: silver;
}
#previewOnlyWarning span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="previewOnlyWarning">
  <span>FOR PREVIEW ONLY<br><br> Do not distribute links from this site.</span>
</div>
```